# How should I express a percentage in a message definition?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm creating a new custom message type for one of my nodes and I need a field that expresses a percentage value (from 0% to 100%).

What is the standard way to express this?  Should I use a floating point variable from 0.0 to 100.0?  Or a floating point from 0.00 to 1.00?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294154/how-should-i-express-a-percentage-in-a-message-definition?/) by [Ricardo Angeli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34859/ricardo-angeli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2018-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-06-20**:
Do you need non-real values, e.g. 12.34%?

**Comment by [Ricardo Angeli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34859/ricardo-angeli/) on 2018-06-20**:
Yes, I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe I found an answer.  Gvdhoorn is right that there is no defined standard.  However, the [sensor_msgs/RelativeHumidity message](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/RelativeHumidity.html) defines relative_humidity as a float64 value from 0.0 to 1.0.  So that's at least one standard message that uses that format for what's traditionally a percentage value.

---

Originally posted by [Ricardo Angeli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34859/ricardo-angeli/) with karma: 41 on 2018-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-06-20**:
So the recommendation is to use a 8 Byte variable to store a value that can fit into 1 Byte?

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-06-20**:
You are making assumptions in your assessment Humpelstilzchen.  One byte is **in general** not sufficient.  What about the representation of 37.7% or even 1/3%?  float64 provides very good precision between 0.0 and 1.0, thus covering the majority of use cases vs something like a uint8.

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-06-20**:
You are now making the assumption that there are fractional. We don't know that since the questioner has not replied to my comment yet.

**Comment by [Ricardo Angeli](https://answers.ros.org/users/34859/ricardo-angeli/) on 2018-06-20**:
In my particular implementation, it is indeed fractional.  But even if it wasn't, wouldn't we want the field type to be able to support a higher-precision value if we want a truly generalized and not implementation-specific message definition?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2018-06-20**:
Still you are wasting a lot of bandwidth since float was not made to cover a small area, but a real large one.  If you do not need human readable I would use an unsigned int and define 0% = 0 and 100% = max value.

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-06-20**:\

> You are now making the assumption that there are fractional

I was not actually, thank you.  I was merely stating that, for the sake of generality, the choice of uint8 would be unwise and gave two examples.  You are now at 4 bytes with your choice of unsigned int (uint32)... is that too much? too

**Comment by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on 2018-06-20**:
little?  If bandwidth is a concern then yes, go ahead and sacrifice readability, make assumptions, and make your own types (that is why such functionality exists) but I wouldn't expect any standard messages to follow suit unless it was in the nature of the underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe there is a standard way to encode a percentage.

> Should I use a floating point variable from 0.0 to 100.0?

That would be one option, yes.

> Or a floating point from 0.00 to 1.00?

I would interprete that as a *ratio*, not a percentage.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1